# Using central limit theorem for approximation

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, approximation

> Let $X$ be a random varaible from a distribution with pdf
>   $$
> f(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}, \quad 0< x < 1.
> $$
>
> a) Name the distribution of $U=-\ln(X)$ by first finding its density
>
> b) Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with pdf given by earlier with $\theta$= 3. Using the result from a) and by the central limit theorem (CLT)
>
> i) find an approximation to  $P(X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot \ldots\cdot X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$

i.e. for the probability of the product of the r.v's.

**My attempt**

I found part a) by doing the transformation, and got an exponential with parameter  $\theta$ where my pdf is: 
$$
f(x)=\theta e^{-u\theta} .
$$
Now where I am struggling is with part i) where I am supposed to find an approximation using the CLT and together with the mean equal to $1/3$ and variance equal to $1/9$. I am able to show that with 30 observation we just take the product of every  mean and variance from each individual observation giving us:

mean = $(\frac{1}{3})^{30}$
variance = $(\frac{1}{9})^{30}$

and then we can just substitute these into the z score by using central limit theorem
$$
P(X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})
= P\left(\frac{X -\mu }{\sigma}\leq \frac {1.85 \cdot 10^{-5} - (\frac{1}{3})^{30}}{(\frac{1}{9})^{15}}  \right)
$$
Hence giving me an answer of 
$ P(Z  \leq 3,808,985,943)$ which definitely cannot be correct. Would appreciate it if somebody could point out my mistake.

**Reattempt:**

Using the hint i got i managed to deduce the following

$P(X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$

$P(log X_1 \cdot log X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot log X_{30} \leq log 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$

P($\sum_{k=1}^{30} log X_i  \leq log 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$

And since X random variable can be normally distributed X~ N( $\frac{1}{3}$ , $\frac{1}{9}$)

Substitute into the Z score

$ P(\frac{ log X -\mu }{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt(n)}})\leq \frac { \frac{log1.85 \cdot 10^{-5}}{30} - (\frac{1}{3})}{(\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\sqrt(n)})} $

$P(Z \leq 11.45)$

Am I on the right track?  Is it correct to use $\mu$ = $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\sigma$ = $\frac{1}{3}$  in the z score?

Comment: This question seems to be a [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) question. Please add the `self-study` tag if appropriate.

Comment: What does the notation $P(X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$ mean? Shouldn't it be $P(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$?

Comment: My apologies Quantlbex, it suppose to be the product of the random variables.  $P(X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot X_3, \ldots,X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5})$   I apologies for the confusion

Comment: And how do we know that the product of i.i.d r.v.'s obeys the "usual" CLT?

Comment: Hint: $-\ln (X_1X_2\cdots X_n) = \sum_i -\ln(X_i) = \sum_i Y_i$ is a sum of exponential random variables $Y_i$. Can you relate $P(X_1X_2\cdots X_n \leq a)$ to $P\left(\sum_i Y_i \leq g(a)\right) = P\left(\sum_i Y_i \leq b\right)$ for some suitably chosen function $g(\cdot)$?

Comment: @Quantibex no, it should be neither that nor what Ingrid did. The CLT is being applied to the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The Op started correctly in the Re-attempt, but then lost it, so I provide the analytical steps.
By the definition of the natural logarithm and its base, we have

$$X_i = \frac 1{e^{-\ln X_i}} \Rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^{30} X_i= \frac 1{\exp{\{\sum_{i=1}^{30}(-\ln X_i)}\}}$$

So

$$P(X_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot X_{30} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5}) = P\left(\frac 1{\exp{\{\sum_{i=1}^{30}(-\ln X_i)}\}} \leq 1.85 \cdot 10^{-5}\right)$$

$$=P\left(\frac {10^5}{1.85}\leq \exp{\{\sum_{i=1}^{30}(-\ln X_i)}\} \right)=P\left(\ln\left(\frac {10^5}{1.85}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{30}(-\ln X_i) \right)$$

$$=1-P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{30}(-\ln X_i)\leq \ln\left(\frac {10^5}{1.85}\right) \right)$$

which is essentially where the OP arrived. But then the CLT is not to be used for *one* variable but for this *sum* of variables.

As already mentioned in the comments, this sum is the sum of i.i.d. exponential random variables, each having mean $1/3$ and variance $1/9$. So the sum, call it $S_n$, has mean and variance $E(S_n) = 30\frac 13 = 10$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S_n)= 30\frac 19 \Rightarrow \sigma_S = \frac {\sqrt{30}}{3}$

Then the normal approximation through the CLT tells us that $[S_n-E(S_n)]/\sigma_S \approx Z\sim N(0,1)$, and then numerical calculations.